# How to download XLSX file from DOI link?

Tags: python, data-science, doi

I want to download two files automatically from Python for a reproducible statistical analysis.

These links

- https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0282068.s001
- https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0282068.s002

I tried

```py
import requests

url = 'https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0282068.s001'

response = requests.get(url)
```

I suspect that the file is actually the content of `response.content`, which appears to be a bunch of encoded information (e.g. `\xe2\x81a\xe4\x1dq\xbe9~3\x94\x885\xba\xc8\x9bz\'~\x1c)X>\xaaXyg\x929\xf84\xc2\x06\t\n x5\`).

How do I download these files and save them as XLSX files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to save the content into the file.

```
import requests

url = 'https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0282068.s001'

response = requests.get(url)
data = response.content

with open('filename.xlsx', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

your content will be saved in file `filename.xlsx`